# Fatal error: kdecoration.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, fatal-error, kde-plasma

I got the following error during the compilation of a project although I've installed `libkdecorations*` :

```
fatal error: kdecoration.h: No such file or directory
```

Kubuntu : 18.04 
KDE : 5.44

Comment: The command `$ dpkg -L libkdecorations2-dev` will show available headers.  `kdecoration.h` is a KDE3, KDE4 header. ... KDE-5 has different header names.

Comment: So probably I need to install development tools of the "kde4" from source, since it's not present in ubuntu 18 repo.

Comment: Your project : Change the header names in the files. Some file.cpp, file.cc, file.h* has kdecoration.h listed. Find it with : `grep -Rn kdecoration.h`